# How to trigger dynamic change on an input?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, trace

I'm trying to use an event like onChange or .change of jQuery, that works when you change inputs value.

This is the js:

```
$(function() {
    $('#deadline').change(function() {
         alert('Message');
    });
});
```

This is the form:

```
<form>
      <input type="title" id="title" />
      <input type="text" id="deadline" value="<?=date('d-m-Y')?>" />

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Deadline input uses date picker (http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php) so when you click on the deadline input, you choose date like in this example http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php and inputs value changes and this change doesn't trigger the alert on js code...

Anyone had experience like this one?

Thank you.

Comment: That particular date picker widget doesn't have a clear event handler for the "onSelect" or "onChange" type of event.  I'd suggest contacting the author to see if there is one that isn't documented, or use a different widget that does support a change event.

Comment: I think the date picker works ok, what I want to reach is to trigger value change by using that date picker. I think you misunderstood if I'm right, I'm trying to trigger the change on input box.

Comment: I understand.  The trick is that the calendar widget sets the value of the field programatically (via script) instead of user action (user typing). As a result, the onchange event on the input doesn't fire.  Therefore it is the responsibility of the widget to provide some sort of means for the end developer to "hook" into an event that indicates something changed. e.g. in the jQueryUI datepicker, there is an "onSelect" event available that a developer can trigger whatever behavior they want.  When I look at the widget you posted, I don't see any event exposed that would help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DOM events are not triggered by changing element's properties via javascript. Typically you would rely on a callback handler provided by the actual library to check when the field has changed, but it doesn't look like this particular library has a callback option. I would suggest using **jQuery UI Datepicker**, which does have this option.